# Circuit analysis

Tags: electrical-engineering, circuits

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3y6c.jpg)
[image]
I don’t understand what is the Use of ‘Vin’ as its anode connects to the open circuit.So I can’t even solve QA

Comment: If vIN is a sine wave, it will vA is a sinewave equal to vIN.  Which can be applied to current source as long as it meets restraints.  It is a FET amplifier, which works on voltage.

Comment: This is a simplified mathematical model of a real circuit. See that no current flows through the open circuit VA, ***BUT*** the current through the current source depends on the voltage across the open circuit VA!

Comment: This is not a circuit made from "real" components. It shows a *mathematical description* of what the real amplifier does. The math equations show how the Vout depends on Va, and in the left hand diagram Vin = Va.

Comment: what is the Use of ‘Vout’ as its anode connects to the open circuit.So I can’t even solve QA.  Same with Vin.  it's there to just say sample this in a manner where current is 0

Comment: We won't do your homework for you. If you still don't understand how to begin a problem like this you should talk to your instructor.

Comment: Thanks for all of your helps, they are really helpful. And   by the way, I’m only a high school student who I trying to learn some knowledge in university, this web is the only approach to ask questions for now